# Python urllib2 open URL and wait some time

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib2

Here is the situation: I want to access the content of an URL in Python via urllib2.

```
import urllib2

    url = www.iwanttoknowwhatsinside.com
    hdr = {
        'User-Agent': 'OpenAnything/1.0 +http://somepage.org/',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }

    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()  
    HTML = opener.open(request).read()
```

This code normally works fine. But if I access a certain page via webbrowser, it says something like *"Checking your browser before accessing ... Your browser will be redirected shortly"* and then the page loads. The URL never changes. ADD: Then I can freely click around on the page, or open a second Tab with the same URL. I only have to wait before the initial access.

If I try to access this page via Python, I get an **urllib2.HTTPError - Service Temporary Not Available** instantly, so I figured urllib2 *doesn't wait that time*. Is there a way to force some waittime before throwing exceptions or retrieving the content? Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: try seeing what is happening by using `curl -v` on the url and add that to your post. for even more detail: `curl --trace-ascii -`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Adding `curl -v` to the url? so I change it to `url = www.something.com curl -v` ?

Comment: sorry, I meant try using a standalone tool called curl which fetches a web page. It is available on most OSes.